# ResourceNotFoundException while adding data to Kinesis Firehose stream using Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to add data to Kinesis Firehose delivery stream using [putrecord](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.put_record)  with python3.6 on aws lambda. When calling put record on the stream I get following exception.

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutRecord operation: Stream MyStream under account 123456 not found.

I am executing following python code to add data to Stream.

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=access_key)
    kinesis_client = session.client('kinesis', region_name='ap-south-1')
    records = event['Records']
    write_records = list()
    count = 0
    for record in records:
        count += 1
        if str(record['eventName']).lower() == 'insert':
            rec = record['dynamodb']['Keys']
            rec.update(record['dynamodb']['NewImage'])
            new_record = dict()
            new_record['Data'] = json.dumps(rec).encode()
            new_record['PartitionKey'] = 'PartitionKey'+str(count)
            # Following Line throws Exception
            kinesis_client.put_record(StreamName="MyStream", Data=new_record['Data'], PartitionKey='PartitionKey'+str(count))

        elif str(record['eventName']).lower() == 'modify':
            pass
    write_records = json.dumps(write_records)

    print(stream_data)
```

MyStream status is active and source for the stream data is set to `Direct PUT and other sources`

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the stream name is correct, you  can create client with regional endpoint of Kinesis

```
kinesis_client = session.client('kinesis', region_name='ap-south-1', endpoint_url='https://kinesis.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/')
```

AWS Service Endpoints List
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Hope this helps !!!